# How to fix Mac OS Ruby installation problems

Tags: ruby, macos

I had to reformat my drive and reinstall Mac OSX. I am trying to figure out how to get this thing working.

Mac OS shipped with Ruby 2.0, but I'm trying to update it to 2.3.1 and install Rails in it. So far, I installed Xcode, Homebrew, and rbenv. I also installed PostgreSQL using Homebrew. I installed Ruby 2.3.1 with rbenv, but it puts it into another folder, and I set it globally, but when I type in `ruby -v` it still shows 2.0.

That's bad, but it gets worse because when I attempt to install Rails, it thinks I've got 2.0 installed and says it needs Ruby > 2.2.

What did I miss?

Comment: I'd recommend reading [the rbenv documentation](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv). It covers how to set up and use rbenv. The whole point of using rbenv (or RVM) is it does put Ruby in your home folder where you can manage it, rather than trying to mangle the Ruby installed by the vendor for their own use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you have missed the `eval "$(rbenv init -)"` in the `.bash_profile`.

Every time I need to prepare my setup from scratch I follow this guide: https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.12-sierra

Comment: thanks, I got it working.  except when i clone my app from github, it says it's in a read only folder.  but it still runs